# How do I set up a 7 day free trial using trial_period_days for Stripe checkout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have attached my current code. It just loads up with the price of £13.99 monthly subscription, the trial isn't added? How do I set this up so that it adds a 7 day free trial?

```
  const checkOut = async (priceId, currency) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  
    const user = auth.currentUser;
  
    console.log("User UID:", user.uid);
    console.log("Attempting to checkout with Price ID:", priceId);
    console.log("Currency for checkout:", currency);
  
    const checkoutSessionCollection = collection(doc(firestore, 'customers', user.uid), 'checkout_sessions');
  
    const successUrl = `${window.location.origin}/payment-success`;
  
    const payload = {
      mode: 'subscription',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [
        {
          price: priceId,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      allow_promotion_codes: true,
      subscription_data: [
          {
              trial_period_days: 7,
            },
         ], 
      success_url: successUrl,
      cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    };
    console.log("Creating checkout session with payload:", payload);
  
    const docRef = await addDoc(checkoutSessionCollection, payload).catch(error => {
      console.error("Error creating checkout session:", error);
    });
  
    console.log("Created checkout session with document ID:", docRef.id);
  
    const checkoutSessionDocRef = doc(firestore, 'customers', user.uid, 'checkout_sessions', docRef.id);
    onSnapshot(checkoutSessionDocRef, async (snap) => {
      console.log("Checkout session snapshot data:", snap.data());
  
      const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
      if (error) {
        console.error("Stripe checkout session error:", error);
        alert(error.message);
      }
      if (sessionId) {
        console.log("Found Stripe session ID:", sessionId);
        const stripe = await loadStripe("TEST_KEY");
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    });
  };
```

I have tried looking everywhere for an answer, but nothing seems to work! Frustrating!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to [Stripe developer support](https://support.stripe.com/), not this community.

Comment: make changes in that place 
`**  line_items: [
      {
        price: priceId,
        quantity: 1,
        subscription_data: {
          trial_period_days: 7, // Add the trial period here
        },
      },
    ],
    allow_promotion_codes: true,
    success_url: successUrl,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  };**`
so it will works

Answer (score 0):

In your code you set:

```
subscription_data: [
   trial_period_days: 7
]
```

But `subscription_data` is not an array but an object. So it should be like this instead:

```
subscription_data: {
   trial_period_days: 7
}
```